# Word 2013 and Activating JS Office App

Tags: office-js

I'm trying to create an office app which will insert merge fields from a defined list (so the user does not need to link to datasource) to a template. I've got Word 2013 and copied a boiler plate example to get me started off. The only issue I have is I can't get the sample add in to display in my word environment. Would someone have a look at the code to see if there is an issue with it displaying in my environment?

Manifest.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<OfficeApp xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/appforoffice/1.1"
           xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
           xsi:type="TaskPaneApp">
    <Id>2b88100c-656e-4bab-9f1e-f6731d86e464</Id>
    <Version>1.0.0.0</Version>
    <ProviderName>Microsoft</ProviderName>
    <DefaultLocale>en-US</DefaultLocale>
    <DisplayName DefaultValue="Boilerplate content" />
    <Description DefaultValue="Insert boilerplate content into a Word document." />
    <Hosts>
        <Host Name="Document"/>
    </Hosts>
    <DefaultSettings>
        <SourceLocation DefaultValue="home.html" />
    </DefaultSettings>
    <Permissions>ReadWriteDocument</Permissions>
</OfficeApp>
```

home.js file

```
Office.initialize = function (reason) {
// Checks for the DOM to load using the jQuery ready function.
$(document).ready(function () {
// After the DOM is loaded, add-in-specific code can run.
// Display initialization reason.
if (reason == "inserted")
write("The add-in was just inserted.");

if (reason == "documentOpened")
write("The add-in is already part of the document.");
});
}

// Function that writes to a div with id='message' on the page.
function write(message){
document.getElementById('message').innerText += message; 
}
```

home.html file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge" />
    <title>Boilerplate text app</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-2.1.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/1/hosted/office.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="home.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
                <h1>Welcome</h1>
        </div>
        <div>
                <p>This sample shows how to add boilerplate text to a document by using the Word JavaScript API.</p>
                <br />
                <h3>Try it out</h3>
                <button id="Salutation">Insert Salutation</button>
                <button id="FirstName">Insert First Name</button>
                <button id="Lastname">Insert Last Name</button>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

As far as I know in word I have gone to options trust centre settings and added the https url where my files are hosted to the trusted catalog url. However the Addin isn't available, so I'm assuming my code is incorrect somewhere. I've also stripped out the home.js so it only had the office initialize but that didn't work either.

Anyone also know whether it is possible to insert a merge field with the new office-js apis?

Comment: When you've got 2 loosely related questions it's generally better to ask 2 separate questions on SO.

Comment: I have changed the home.js to the fully qualified domain name where it is being hosted which also has https. It's still not appearing as one of my addins. I am right in thinking the manifest file should be in the same folder as the js and html file?

Comment: The manifest does not need to be in the same folder as the other files. Can you see home.html in your browser?

Comment: You're url should be to home.html, not home.js (perhaps just a typo though :) The manifest file is what tells Office where to go find your app - it doesn't sit on your web server, it gets loaded by Office (Visual Studio does this for you if you're using the Office Add-In templates; in production this might be via the Office Store or some other methods for internal add-ins)

Answer (score 3):

Regarding not having your add-in display in Word, you'll need to update the SourceLocation to point at the URL where your add-in is hosted.

Regarding your second question, I don't know whether you can insert a merge field, but there are ways to [bind to a text area](https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/shared/binding.textbinding?product=word). I suggest that you also look at this sample, [Word-Add-in-JavaScript-AddPopulateBindings](https://github.com/OfficeDev/Word-Add-in-JavaScript-AddPopulateBindings).

Answer (score 0):

It can't find "home.html". That's going to need to be a complete url. You need to be running home.html off of a web server (and it needs to be using https).

If you are using Visual Studio, I'd suggest you start a new project using the Office add-in templates and copy your sample, it will set you up with a URL that starts with ~ and gets translated to the right thing on build.

If you are using something else, [here's the documentation](http://dev.office.com/docs/add-ins/get-started/create-an-office-add-in-using-any-editor) but your url will look something like `<SourceLocation DefaultValue="https://localhost:8443/app/home/home.html"/>`